# C++ doesn't compile my custom data type including a vector in it

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I tried to do a custom list, which has intern a private vector.

yet I allways get this Error-message, and have no idea where even start to look for the problem. I use Qt, windows and "CONFIG += c++11" within my project.

```
...myPath\c++\bits\stl_construct.h:75: Error: call of overloaded 'myDataType()' is ambiguous
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
   ^
```

What does this errormessage tries to tell me here? Where should I start to look?

thanks for any hint.

Edit: Constructors for lists:

```
/***********************************************************************
* Constructors and a Destructor
* *********************************************************************/
datatype_collection::datatype_collection(){
    std::vector<datatype> erg (0);
    m_datatype_list = erg;
}

datatype_collection::~datatype_collection(){
}
```

for datatype:

```
/***********************************************************************
* Constructors and a Destructor - Implemented because of the rule of 3
* *********************************************************************/
datatype::datatype(float value)
    : m_datatype( to_datatype(value) ){
}

datatype::datatype(int32_t value)
    : m_datatype(value){
}

fix_point::~fix_point(){
}
```

Edit2: There is a lot of more text, but it isn't directly marked as the error:

```
...\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\vector:62: In file included from 

.../mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/vector:62:0,

...\QtCreator\bin\myFolder\datatype_collection.h:25: from ..\myFolder\datatype_collection.h:25,

...\QtCreator\bin\myFolder\datatype_collection.cpp:1: from ..\myFolder\datatype_collection.cpp:1:

...\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h:-1: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = fix_point; _Args = {}]':

...\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:495: required from 'static void std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = fix_point*; _Size = unsigned int; bool _TrivialValueType = false]'

...\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:544: required from 'void std::__uninitialized_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = fix_point*; _Size = unsigned int]'

...\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:605: required from 'void std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _ForwardIterator = fix_point*; _Size = unsigned int; _Tp = fix_point]'

...\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:1225: required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_initialize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = fix_point; _Alloc = std::allocator<fix_point>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]'

...\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:271: required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = fix_point; _Alloc = std::allocator<fix_point>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<fix_point>]'

...\QtCreator\bin\Aufgabe2Punkt1\datatype_collection.cpp:8: required from here

...\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h:75: Error: call of overloaded 'datatype()' is ambiguous
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^

...\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h:75: candidates are:

...\QtCreator\bin\myFolder\datatype_collection.h:24: In file included from ..\myFolder\datatype_collection.h:24:0,

...\QtCreator\bin\myFolder\datatype_collection.cpp:1: from ..\myFolder\datatype_collection.cpp:1:

...\QtCreator\bin\myFolder\datatype.hpp:48: datatype::datatype(int32_t)
     datatype(int32_t value=0);         //constructor with default value

...\QtCreator\bin\myFolder\fixpoint.hpp:47: datatype::datatype(float)
     datatype(float value=0);           //constructor with default value
     ^
```

Update:
I found what causes the trouble, but I have no idea why it causes the problems:

```
/****************************************************************
 * overloading of the []-operator
 * *************************************************************/
const datatype& datatype_collection::operator[](int value) const{ //read-only

    return m_datatype_list[value];
}
```

This method causes the error as seen above.

Comment: You overloaded your constructors ambiguously?

Comment: Its impossible to say for sure without actually seeing the code that is causing the error.

Comment: Why don't you just show your code to us?

Comment: The code is pretty long, but I could add the constructors, if they might be the problem

Comment: @Nerethar: it means that the compiler or even a human cannot tell without biasment how to construct in your case. Anything can be the problem. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: The error message needs context. It is impossible to tell you what it means when we don't know what code it is complaining about.

Comment: Is it whole the error? That's strange that it is shows an error in a system header, so I suspect that's now whole an error.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: yet, someone gave a pity upvote... it is a pity. These questions need to be fixed by the OPs or burn.

Comment: @lpapp that was me ;) I don't like when someone downvotes without a reasons being written to the topicstarter. So, you was the one, who did it, right?

Comment: I edited the constructors into the question, maybe thats a start, as Columbo suggested

Comment: @Hi-Angel: yes, I downvoted it since it did not give essential information. With your pity upvote, you encourage that pattern. :( Even after the update, the code is incomplete to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @lpapp let's keep this pattern as an out little secret ♥ When someone does a downvote, they should explicitly give the information why was this. If I was a newbie, I couldn't understand from the comments here so far, why these people downvoted me → either because of scarce of information, either because of «newbish question». And believe me, I'd tend to the second, although the right reason is the first one.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: I downvoted after two attempts made in comments. Please only upvote posts that are good, not because they got an IMHO deserved downvote which is also explained more than once. I will turn my downvote into an upvote if I see a reproducable example.

Comment: I don't want to be rude or anything, but do I have enough informations in here now, or is still something wrong with my post? I would prefer not to post like 500 lines of text here, just to get a hint where to look for problems :/

Comment: Please narrow your problem down to a single test case and we will be able to solve it for you or you may even solve it for yourself on the way.

Comment: @Nerethar I don't even see this `myDataType()` about which the error says in the posted code. Also, is this a whole an error message? Are there anything more?

Comment: @lpapp how did you knew it was me? A guess?

Comment: @Hi-Angel: `@lpapp that was me ;)`

Comment: @lpapp no, before that comment you explicitly wrote to me. But now I see, just a guess.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: I wrote to you without knowing who upvoted this. As you stated yourself the issue, I thought you would feel some sympathy. :D

Comment: I just edited my post again. There were indeed more messages, but I was too focused on that one marked as error to even notice :/ But still, I have to little knowledge to know what is happening here :/ But it seems like something with the constructors might be wrong, as Columbo suggested.

Comment: @Nerethar the problem is that you have two constructors with a default values. The call `datatype()` at the line 8 is ambiguous: which one should be chosen? As far as I know, you couldn't resolve this by anything with an exception of just removing one of a default values.

Comment: That indeed fixed the problem. Can you please transform it into an answer? I also wonder why this only crashed with the use of the [] function. I had a testprogramm run over datatype.cpp and it worked fine :/

Comment: I can't transform that to the answer cuz the question is closed :D Hard to say without viewing the code why it did worked before. I guess for some reason that code didn't used the default constructor.

Comment: Anyways, thank you very much Sir, you just saved me from searching for houres :D

Comment: @Hi-Angel I gave you credit within the question and edited the solution in, so for the rare circumstances that somebody looks for this, he might find a solution^^

Comment: Voted to reopen. Please create a separate answer and remove the "answer" from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by [Hi-Angel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2388257/hi-angel):

> the problem is that you have two constructors with a default values. The call datatype() at the line 8 is ambiguous: which one should be chosen? As far as I know, you couldn't resolve this by anything with an exception of just removing one of a default values.

<sub>Disclaimer: this was extracted from the question and posted here on the OP's behalf.</sub>